# Standard functions not working in web worker

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

I am trying to implement web workers in my application but for some reason functions like `alert` and console `error` with undefined.

My web worker code:

```
AJAX = new XMLHttpRequest();

AJAX.open("GET", 'Record/fetchEntity', true);
AJAX.send();

var result = AJAX.responseText;
console.log(result); // Errors with 'console is not defined'.
self.postMessage(result);
```

By the way, `result` is an array of objects. Will this pass back ok to the master the way I have done it?

Comment: Because they are not supported in the web worker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web workers have no direct access to the browser or DOM.  There is a specific subset of browser related functions that they can access listed [here in the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Worker/Functions_available_to_workers)

- atob()
- btoa()
- clearInterval()
- clearTimeout()
- dump()
- setInterval()
- setTimeout()
- XMLHttpRequest()
- Worker()

Other than that they can only access the core standard JS functions and a few extra worker things

- importScripts()
- FileReaderSync()